# What to do after opening a potentially malicious link on smartphone?

Tags: malware, mobile, sms, scam

What must one do if they opened a malicious link?

**Warning**: Please do not open the links below as they may be malicious. They have been deliberately mangled to prevent accidental opening

I received an SMS from an Australian mobile number
"Hello We have your package in queue: `https://stone-static.rootedlabs.com/a.php?ipmh9o3`"

Analysis: https://cuckoo.ee/analysis/2383830/summary

I got the same message from another number and it read:
"Hello. We have your package in queue: `https://eliquidhut.com/p.php?304ybfegx`"

Analysis: https://cuckoo.ee/analysis/2383864/summary

These links redirected me to the same website which is the official Steam website (store.steampowered.com). It sometimes redirected me to the steam official website then sometimes to Huawei official website and sometimes to University of Michigan official website.

I have moderately sensitive information stored on my devices such as bank passwords and emails.
What steps should I take to ensure my device is not compromised?

Comment: I used wget to grab the HTML from the links provided and reviewed it.  There is a LOT of code, but from the looks of it, it doesn't seem to be redirecting you as much as faking real websites and then spoofing the address bar to make it seem like your really on the page.  Its most likly trying to steal your credentials.  Clicking on it prob didnt do any real dmg, maybe just reboot the phone to make sure the cache is cleared and carry on w/ your life.  If your super paranoid you could factory reset your phone.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a part of a known and ongoing flubot scam that is currently affecting multiple Australian users who are receiving text messages on their phones with a malicious link.

Previously their texts had typos and contained a link to download a malicious app APK that could steal banking information. Since September they have updated their methods and now their messages talk about delivery notifications which may contain an APK link to download a software. You can read about it here: https://www.scamwatch.gov.au/news-alerts/missed-delivery-call-or-voicemail-flubot-scams.

The style of URL and message also matches the message you received. However, the links you have provided do not seem to download anything so I am not sure how it might be working in this case.

I recommend just clearing your cache and restarting your device.

Answer (score -1):

Those links look like your average scammer trying to make you enter your personal information into a scam site. However, I doubt that those sites can do any damage to your device if you didn't interact with it.
To make sure, you might want to restart your device, clear your cache, and done.

Comment: All the redirects that happen *before* the final site appears can certainly try to do harm without interaction ...

Answer (score -1):

I checked the first link and it seemed to be related to a scam.
(Do not worry for me opening the link, I did it in a virtual machine while connected to a VPN in russia)

The first time the link took a moment loading and then redirected me to the next page:
[image]

But after trying to open it again I saw this:

[image]

Based on my experience, I'm almost sure that it is an information grabber.
Why do I think that?

1. The URL Contains ?ipmh9o3, which could be used to identify the person who used it. It is very common for information grabber sites, to add an identifiers to the URL, so that they know who opened the URL.
2. They redirect to a random page.  In this case if it were a scam there would be some form or fake website that would ask you for your login details or other information but there is nothing like that. That makes me think that its an information grabber.

### What can someone do if you opened that link?

They will know your IP Address, they could track you to where you live (possibly), they can gather information about your device, browser, version, Internet provider, etc, etc.

All of that information could be just to study you, analyze possible attacks or try to find exploits to get access to your device.

If they know for example that you use an iPhone, that you used Safari in a specific version, they could prepare a more advanced attack for your particular device.

I think they will be confused because in the case that that link is in fact an information grabber link, they will see your phone and a connection from Russia.

The second link looks like the same thing but it redirects to other website that also shows 404 Error.

[image]

### What can you do about it?

1. First of all, remember to never open any suspicious link again.
2. I suggest you to update all your software, download some antivirus/antimalware/antispyware app to scan your device just in case.
3. If you have the possibility you could optionally get a VPN, so in the case that someone forces a situation in which you have to open something that could be used to trace you using your IP Address, they see that you are in Japan or in other unexpected location.

Never trust anyone. Its good to trust, but its better not to do it.

Comment: Next time, open malicious links in malware analysis sandboxes to 1. protect your machines, and 2. get the actual info, not what appears on the screen. https://cuckoo.ee/ is a well-known free one. I've added links to actual analysis in the question.

Comment: Yes an analysis sandbox would have been a better option. Although that was a Virtual Machine, so there is no problem if it is "destroyed" or infected because I could just restore it or even delete it and create a new one. And the part of "what appears on the screen" was just to show that you could get redirected to a "real website", it could even be the website of Microsoft which is also something that happens in the information grabbers. The malicious part is in the link that then redirects to a non-malicious website.

Comment: @schroeder by the way. Why edit the OP's question to add the analysis instead of answering with the analysis and tell us the result? You seem to know better than must of us what's happening and what we could do to stay safe (Sorry if I sound aggressive or something, Im pretty knew to security stackexchange).

Comment: Because there is a massive difference between an analysis of the links and an answer to what was asked "what do I do next?" The OP isn't asking for analysis but a response. And since everyone is speculating about what those links did, based on what the browser showed them in order to come up with their answer for what to do next, I thought that spending 2 minutes to curtail the speculation would be useful.

Comment: Re: "because I could just restore it or even delete it" -- could? I assume that you have already blown that VM away?

Comment: Alright, I get your point. Next time I'll not speculate. You should really answer the question, you seem to know the answer or to be able to get the answer. And that VM is still working, I just use It for testing and I restore to a previous snapshot after doing something like opening a potentially dangerous link, program, etc. I don't see the problem, its not my main machine, I don't use it to open any account, etc.